# Generate random circles in JavaScript with random colors

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas

I have the following code in JavaScript. It is a script that generates a random circle. I would like to generate 1000 circles using for loop with different colors. How would I do that?

Here is my code:

```
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();    

    ctx.arc(Math.floor(Math.random()*(100)+1) , Math.floor(Math.random()*(80)+1), Math.floor(Math.random()*(20)+1), 0 ,2*Math.PI); 

    ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: You had it, you just needed to wrap it in a for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had it; you just needed to wrap it in a for loop:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

for(var i=0;i<1000;i++){
   ctx.strokeStyle ="#" +  Math.floor(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF).toString(16);
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(Math.floor(Math.random()*(100)+1) , Math.floor(Math.random()*(80)+1), Math.floor(Math.random()*(20)+1), 0 ,2*Math.PI);
   ctx.stroke();
}
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/jebec/3/edit)

Comment: Each of these circles appears to be black instead of randomly colored.